# How to write a dictionary with tuple key and integer value to a fle?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary with tuple key and integer value.
Like this:

```
{(3, 935): 1, (3, 9594): 1, (2, 4593): 1}
```

And I want to write this into a text file. However when I tried to use json, I found json only supports string format so I failed.
I also tried to convert key to string at first.
Like this:

```
for key in dict:
    key_str = str(key)
    tmp_str_dict = {key_str : dict[key]}
    str_dict = dict(Counter(str_dict)+Counter(tmp_str_dict))
    print len(str_dict)
```

But there was a perfomance issue which was too slow.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Shivam Singh Sorry, I have solved this problem. But still, thanks for reply.